# Why does onClick require two click events to fire on Android, but not iOS? (Titanium)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm experiencing a consistent problem with onClick functions in Android apps build using Titanium. I've set up some very simple switches which manipulate visibility and/or styles, and what invariably happens is they behave perfectly on iOS, but **on Android they require an extra 'click' before working normally** (the first time you click something when the page loads). The first click only needs to happen once, so it's not that *everything* requires a double-click but rather that the very first click you perform is ignored.

Sample JS:

```
function infoToggleTabBio(){
    if($.infoWebView.visible){
        $.infoWebView.hide();
        $.bioWebView.show();
        $.bioToggle.applyProperties({backgroundColor:'#fff',color:'#008ead'});
        $.artToggle.applyProperties({backgroundColor:'transparent',color:'#fff'});
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Can you show the code where the click event is added?